# how to include namespaces in headers without injecting them into clients?

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-libraries, using

I've got a lot of legacy code that I'd like to organize a bit better and put our libraries into namespaces.

As such, I've got a bunch of headers which #include "my library thing.h"

And I'd like to move the contents of "my library thing" into various namespaces, such as:

```
namespace Toolbox::AFX;  // application framework extensions
```

But I'm constantly butting up against C++'s rules (limitations) for where I'm allowed to do namespace injection.

I want to #include the headers in some of my client headers - so I have access to various library facilities and classes - but I *don't* want to turn around and inject those namespaces right back out into my client's translation units!

e.g.

```
#include "AccelTable.h"  // my library's ACCEL management class lives here

class Foo
{
   CAccelTable   m_hotkeys;     // use the darn thing
   ...
};
```

But the CAccelTable is no longer valid if I put it inside of a namespace.

I cannot do the obvious:

```
class Foo
{
   using namespace Toolbox::AFX;   // <<-- error
   CAccelTable   m_hotkeys;     // use the darn thing
   ...
};
```

And IIRC, this injects the namespace into callers:

```
#include "AccelTable.h"  // my library's ACCEL management class lives here
using namespace Toolbox::AFX;  // d'oh - now all my clients are forced to enjoy this entire namespace in their translation units!  YUK!

class Foo
{
   CAccelTable   m_hotkeys;     // use the darn thing
   ...
};
```

Now, I know I can do annoying and tedious things like:

```
class Foo
{
   Toolbox::AFX::CAccelTable   m_hotkeys;     // use the darn thing
   ...
};
```

or

```
class Foo
{
   using CAccelTable = Toolbox::AFX::CAccelTable;
   CAccelTable   m_hotkeys;     // use the darn thing
   ...
};
```

Do I have this right?

Is there a better way?  This seems obnoxious to have to go through piles of headers and not just add a single `using namespace` for the client headers but have to name every single class or type with an alias in every single class or type that uses them!  That adds up to a rather HUGE number of edits.

Comment: typedef Toolbox::AFX::CAccelTable CAccelTable.  If you have a number of these, just put them in their own header.

Comment: I have an entire library of types and multiple software projects which make use of them.  Maybe a few thousands of references.

Comment: "entire library of types" so you'd need a typedef for all the ones you use publicly.
"thousands of references" - not one of these would need to change.

Comment: ah, I see - so put typedefs or aliases outside of the ns for all of the library headers themselves to expose the consumable types in the global ns.  Interesting idea.

Comment: you can put it in the ns - so that myNamespace::CAccelTable is Toolbox::AFX::CAccelTable;

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like a workable solution for me.  Maybe this is even a nice root of what will become the export statements for C++?? module system. :D